# how to concatenate two positive integers using macros?

Tags: c, macros

I need to write a program to join two positive integers to form another positive integer using macros. Example , if `x=12`, `y=35` and the answer should be `1235`. How should I do this?

Comment: What language or environment are these macros in?

Comment: I am using c language for this

Comment: @Aye: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use the ## operator

> It is often useful to merge two tokens into one while expanding macros. This is called token pasting or token concatenation. The ‘##’ preprocessing operator performs token pasting. When a macro is expanded, the two tokens on either side of each ‘##’ operator are combined into a single token, which then replaces the ‘##’ and the two original tokens in the macro expansion. Usually both will be identifiers, or one will be an identifier and the other a preprocessing number. When pasted, they make a longer identifier. This isn’t the only valid case. It is also possible to concatenate two numbers (or a number and a name, such as 1.5 and e3) into a number. Also, multi-character operators such as += can be formed by token pasting.

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

So, in your case, `#define CONCAT_NUMBER(FIRST, SECOND) (FIRST ## SECOND)` should work

Comment: @Caleb This works if the tokens are known at compile-time, even for number tokens, test it https://onlinegdb.com/B1mhWK2s4

Answer (score 0):

> Example , if x=12, y=35 and the answer should be 1235. How should I do this?

You need to shift `x` left by some number of decimal digits that depends on the number of digits in `y`. So what is the number of digits in `y`? Well, it's the integer part of `log(y)`. And to accomplish the shift, you need to multiply `x` by 10 raised to that value. So the mathematical expression you need is, depending on the language you're using, something like:

```
finalValue = x*(10^^(floor(log(y))) + y;
```

Translate that into your language of choice and you should have what you want.

Comment: This will incure runtime-penalty and/or relies on the compiler to deduce that it does not change in value. A macro-based solution is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass variable x and y to the MACRO then this cannot be done. As Macro expansion happens at compile-time.

In case if you want to pass the direct value to the macro then concatenation can be done as follows-

`#define CONCATENATE(NUM_1, NUM_2) (NUM_1 ## NUM_2)`

Comment: Don't you like my `CONCAT1` macro?

Comment: I executed and verified your code. It works and gives the expected output. The only limitation is the size.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a simple macro if the numbers are integer literals. For the general case, you must compute the result or use a very cumbersome macro:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* Simple token pasting macro, x and y must be literals */
#define CONCAT(x,y) x ## y

/* Elaborate macro: arguments are evaluated multiple times */
#define CONCAT1(x, y) ((y) + (x) * (\
                       (y) < 10 ? 10 :\
                       (y) < 100 ? 100 :\
                       (y) < 1000 ? 1000 :\
                       (y) < 10000 ? 10000 :\
                       (y) < 100000 ? 100000 :\
                       (y) < 1000000 ? 1000000 :\
                       (y) < 10000000 ? 10000000 :\
                       (y) < 100000000 ? 100000000 :\
                       1000000000))

int main() {
    int x = 12;
    int y = 35;
    int result;

    /* Solution with simple macro only for literals */
    result = CONCAT(12, 35);
    printf("%d\n", result);

    /* Solution with long macro */
    result = CONCAT1(x, y);
    printf("%d\n", result);

    /* Generic solution */
    result = x * 10;
    for (int i = y; i > 10; i /= 10)
        result *= 10;
    result += y;
    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1235
1235
1235
```

As can be seen on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/RfayV5), the compiler generates the same code for all 3 approaches because `x` and `y` have known values.